# Delphi XE8 update 1 Xcode 6.4 Invalid Signature

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi

I just submitted a release a week ago.
Started getting this message on 2 separate accounts for the last couple days using application loader. You get the email below after uploading. I have re-created cert, profile, even tried wildcard app identifier.

Invalid Signature - The binary with bundle identifier 'com.domain.appname' at path [appname.app] contains an invalid signature. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target.

Comment: Well, are you using a Development certificate? Or do you have a proper deployment certificate? If the latter, have you tried to completely clean your compiled files and re-building your app from scratch?

Comment: I am using a distribution certificate and appstore provisioning profile. I have even revoked and regenerated new ones. Submissions were working fine a week ago.  I just built a blank project and tried to submit and receive this message during upload: ITMS-90034: "Missing or invalid signature. The bundle 'com.domain.appname' at bundle path 'Payload/Project1.app' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate."]

Answer (score 1):

It seems a temporal glitch on iTunes. It is working again, just submit your app and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled XE8 and reinstalled. Now all is working correctly.